# how to restrict flutter app to take screen shots?

Tags: android, flutter

how to restrict users to take screen shots of the course app?

1. the flutter app is targeting android platform.
2. the app will be using PDF view and video courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainActivity` class, inside the android project dir in your Flutter Project
Add the following `import` to your `MainActivity` class:

`import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;`

Add the following line to your `MainActivity's` onCreate method:

**`getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`**

It will solve the problem you are facing, and restrict the OS from taking the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest to do that is by using the [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) plugin

First import its latest version in pubspec.yaml file of your Flutter project and run pub get. Then add the below code inside the widget's initState() method for which you want to disable screenshot and screen recording.

```
Future<void> secureScreen() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE); 
 }

 @override
 void initState() {
    secureScreen();
    super.initState();
 }
```

If you want to make your whole app screenshot disable just call securescreen() method (defined above) inside your main() function in main.dart file.

option 2:

Write this below code in the `MainActivity.java file.`

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
  }
```

and importing these packages!

```
import android.view.WindowManager; 
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.os.Bundle; // required for onCreate parameter
```